# Mixture of Priors/Algebra?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, model-selection, conditional-probability, mixture-distribution

Can someone explain how the author gets to the expression after the words "This leads to:"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I must acknowledge the explanation from this excerpt of [a CUNY solution manual](http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/~saad/courses/bayes/hw/hw5sol.pdf) is not the clearest, especially the part about the posterior given the prior.

If the question is about the algebra of
$$\dfrac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{A}{B}$$
leading to $$\alpha=\dfrac{A}{A+B}$$ there is not much to explain.

It the question is about the weight $2$, it is a consequence of the prior weights of $2/3$ and $1/3$ on the two priors.

From a more general perspective, the pair $(\mu,x)$ is distributed from the mixture
$$\frac{2}{3}\varphi(x-\mu)\varphi(\mu)+\frac{1}{3}\varphi(x-\mu)\varphi(\mu-1)$$Therefore, the conditional density of $\mu$ given $x=2$ is$$\frac{2}{3}\varphi(2-\mu)\varphi(\mu)+\frac{1}{3}\varphi(2-\mu)\varphi(\mu-1)$$with
$$\eqalign{\varphi(2-\mu)\varphi(\mu)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\frac{-1}{2}\{4-4\mu+\mu^2+\mu^2\}\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\frac{-2}{2}\{\mu^2-2\mu+1\}\exp\frac{-1}{2}\{4-2\}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi/2}}\exp\frac{-2}{2}\{\mu-1\}^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\times 2}}\exp\{-1\}}$$which is a Normal $\text{N}(1,1/2)$ density multiplied by the factor$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1\}$$Similarly,
$$\eqalign{
\varphi(2-\mu)\varphi(\mu-1)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\frac{-1}{2}\{4-4\mu+\mu^2+\mu^2-2\mu+1\}\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\frac{-2}{2}\{\mu^2-3\mu+9/4\}\exp\frac{-1}{2}\{5-9/2\}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi/2}}\exp\frac{-2}{2}\{\mu-3/2\}^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\times 2}}\exp\{-1/4\}
}$$which is a Normal $\text{N}(1,1/2)$ density multiplied by the factor$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1/4\}$$This means in conclusion that the conditional distribution of $\mu$ given $x=2$ is the mixture
$$\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1\}\text{N}(1,1/2)+
\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1/4\}\text{N}(1,1/2)$$
up to the normalising constant
$$1\Big/\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1\}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\exp\{-1/4\}$$

Comment: If you can explain the question + solution in general, I think that would be helpful also...

Comment: Since you post a homework problem with a solution, this pertains to a `self-study` question: in such cases it is useful to understand what you do not understand and where you get stuck. So please detail further your question in this spirit.